Text gets cut off between pages when exporting html to pdf using html2pdf
I am trying to export my some of my html pages as a pdf so that they can be printed. The problem is that most of them exceed the standard A4 height. Their data is input by users and is displayed dynamically so I am unable to control how long each of the html pages are. This causes a lot of the text to get cut off between pages like so:

I am using the html2pdf module to export my html pages as pdf. Here is my export code below:


$scope.exportToPDF = function() {
  $scope.export = true;

  // Execute the rest of the code after a timeout
  setTimeout(function() {
    // html2pdf options
    const options = {
      filename: 'Curriculum.pdf',
    };

    // Collect content from each page
    var pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
    var combinedContent = '';

    pages.forEach(function(page) {
      combinedContent += '<div class="page-content">' + page.innerHTML + '</div>';
    });

    // Create a new div element to hold the combined content
    var combinedPagesDiv = document.createElement('div');
    combinedPagesDiv.innerHTML = combinedContent;

    // Export the combined content as a PDF
    html2pdf().set(options).from(combinedPagesDiv).save();

  }, 100); // Adjust the timeout duration as needed
};



How should I go about solving this issue?
